# Uploading the video through iPhone App programmatically

Tags: iphone

How can we upload the video through iPhone App programmatically, can any one please provide me some sample code for the same.

Got a sample from:
http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/

But always getting "NoLinkedYouTubeAccount Error" while uploading the video.

Please help me.

Many Thanks
iPhone Developer

Comment: You just need to login to youtube

Comment: Are you talking about generic upload to a server via HTTP or something else, or specifically uploading to YouTube?

Comment: need to upload on the YouTube specifically, actually working on the app which would have a feature to upload the video directly on the YouTube

Comment: @AbSingh : If you could find a solution, please post it here. It may help others :)

Answer (score 4):

Sign in via web to your account. Subscribe to a channel and it will work. This must link your Google's account to your Youtube's account.

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved similar problem by creating a channel in Youtube's account. Please check for the settings of Youtube's account before uploading the video.